# How to find all parent elements using Selenium C# WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a variable that is a `By` class. I wish to call `FindElements` to return the corresponding element as well as all of the parent elements of this `By`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to find the `By` element and then the parents up until the root.

You can just use XPath to get the parent element until you get to the page root. So something like this:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementTree(By by)
{
    List<IWebElement> tree = new List<IWebElement>();

    try
    {
        IWebElement element = this.driver.FindElement(by);
        tree.Add(element); //starting element

        do
        {
            element = element.FindElement(By.XPath("./parent::*")); //parent relative to current element
            tree.Add(element);

        } while (element.TagName != "html");
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
    }

    return new ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>(tree);
}
```

Optionally you can stop on the `body` element instead of the `html` one.

Also note that this is fairly slow, especially if its a deeply nested element. A faster alternative would be to use `ExecuteScript` to run a javascript snippet that uses the same logic and then returns all the elements at once.

Comment: As mentionned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45769799/233906 `By.XPath("./ancestor-or-self::*")` should achieve the same and return all ancestors (including parent).

Answer (score 3):

I created WebElement extension, I hope useful.

```
public static IWebElement GetElementParentByClass(this IWebElement element, string ClassName)
{
    try
    {
        IWebElement parent = element;
        do
        {
            parent = parent.FindElement(By.XPath("./parent::*")); //parent relative to current element

        } while (!parent.GetAttribute("class").Equals(ClassName));

        return parent;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```