# Selenium IDE verify if two elements are adjacent to each other

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have to verify if a button is adjacent to a textarea using java , selenium IDE.

The textarea and the button are seperated by a spacing ( this is also included in the xpath). As far as what i have done is to just check if the text is present.

```
Boolean element_button = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//...").size()!=0;
```

Similar for text area.But how is it possible to verify if they are adjacent.

Comment: Show relevant part of the HTML (includes the button and the textarea)

Comment: get the [parent element[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021074/how-to-find-all-parent-elements-using-selenium-c-sharp-webdriver) of each and compare

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

1. Compare the Parent element of both the elements.
2. You can compare the `y` co-ordinate using `webElement1.getLocation().y` for both the button and textarea , this should be same for both.
3. Then you can compare the difference between the `x` co-ordinate using `webElement2.getLocation().x` for both elements and compare it with the width of first webelement and little space if it's there .