# Is it possible to find to find all parent tags of a html tag at once for web scraping?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and I was wondering that instead of finding a desired tag and backtracking each of its parents tag, is there a better way to do it? where I can all the tags from the  `body` to our desired tag at once?

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021074/how-to-find-all-parent-elements-using-selenium-c-sharp-webdriver  I think backtracking is the only way.

Comment: Okay Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, using beautifulsoup is the best way to do it. (in python)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

//parse html using BeautifulSoup
doc = BeautifulSoup("html link", features="lxml")//add .getText() for no tags

//loop through all lines in body (including tags)
for d in doc:
     print(d)
```

You can then replace the print statement with maybe d.find("tag") to find where the tag is and get information.

I think that a better way would to just use seleniums find_element_by_xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("link")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your xpath")
```

Hopefully this helps, welcome to web automation, its a fun world!