# Find out protractor element CSS chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-selectors, protractor

For development and debugging purposes it would be really good to know what is the full chain of CSS I'm asking in methods like:

```
divElm.element(by.css("article")).element(by.css("tbody > tr")).then(function(elm) {
  // is there a way to know here what is the "CSS chain" of 'elm'?
});
```

If I debug `elm` I see a `locator` property with:

```
locator_: { using: 'css selector', value: 'tbody > tr' },
```

But that's only the locator of the last element in the chain.

It would be really useful to have all, like: `divElm, article, tbody > tr` in this way I'd be able to debug this manually on the page to see if the element really exists or not.

**UPDATE**: what I really need is, when a Protractor selector expectation **fails** (e.g. using isPresent() method), the error I get only shows the *last* selector in the chain. It would be really handy if the whole chain is shown.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, because getting parent element can be achieved through other ways too. Even Selenium hasn't included such method - [here's a link of that](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/UDdU8FkQTSo). However you can use xpath to get to the parent element. [Here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18001659/4180674)

Comment: Do you want the exact values you've used in Protractor to reach the element or the full DOM path withing HTML document?

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question was confusing. I want the exact selectors / values I used in Protractor to reach the element, not the full DOM path.

Comment: Why would you need it when it's declared right there: element(by.css("article")).element(by.css("tbody > tr")) ?

Comment: Well, you got the point. This is a simplified example. If you implement something like PageObjects concept, or you have a more complex hierarchical object relationship (ej: Page > section > header) then you might waste some time trying to know what's the complete protractor selector.

I'm able to discover the full chain, but it takes some time if I the selector has many parents. And the only error I get in a failed expectation is related only with the LAST selector in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a CSS chain right from your browser, the easiest way to do it is do what is suggested in that excellent article:
http://yizeng.me/2014/03/23/evaluate-and-validate-xpath-css-selectors-in-chrome-developer-tools/

That way you don't have to debug it anymore, you know right from the start what your selector matches (and what it doesn't)

Comment: I'm familiar with Google / FF Developer Tools. The problem is that I usually have to reconstruct the whole CSS chain because I have a hierarchy of objects, e.g. Page > section > header, so I have to look for the parent... etc. 

So what I really want is, when an expectation fail because a selector, to have ALL the protractor selectors displayed in the error and not only the last selector in the chain.

Comment: Another option is to add IDs to your elements. That way you won't waste any more time with complex selectors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, the last element occurs the error, so if you want to see the full locator, try to select the element in one step. For example:

`var el = element(by.css("article > tbody > tr"));`

However it is not the best for you, so you can reach the inner HTML with protractor with `getInnerHtml()`, if you want to identify the element.

You can get the locators one by one. For eg.: `divElm locator` and `divElm.element(by.css("article")) locator` etc.