# How to click a parent element using the child element for the following scenario

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using selenium webdriver to automate. I have a special case below.

```
<div id = "A">
  <div id = "container">
    <div id="innercontainer">
      <div>
       <div id="ruleContainer">
         <span id="rule">CNET</span>
         <div id="name">CNET></div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href = "#....."></a>
</div>
<div id = "A">
  <div id = "container">
    <div id="innercontainer">
      <div>
       <div id="ruleContainer">
         <span id="rule">GNET</span>
         <div id="name">GNET></div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href = "#....."></a>
</div>`<div id = "A">
  <div id = "container">
    <div id="innercontainer">
      <div>
       <div id="ruleContainer">
         <span id="rule">DNET</span>
         <div id="name">DNET></div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href = "#....."></a>
</div>`
```

Here I need to click on element A with text CNET... I am able to get to the child CNET but it is a dead element. So I need to click on anchor for element A having that particular child.

How can I do that? Is there a way? I know the solution for looping but my application refreshes so often and I encounter stale exception because of it. So could some one give me a better solution like navigating back to the parent and then to the sibling and click().

Comment: Here's a related post about clicking the parent element, for once you have found the element with 'CNET' text. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577636/select-parent-element-of-known-element-in-selenium . As a side note, as I'm not super familiar with selenium but you probably don't want to have multiple elements with the same ID='A', instead you could use a semantic class name like 'container-parent' or something similiar.

Comment: seems there is one div too much opened in every id='A' area

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this xpath:

```
//div[@id='A' and .//span[contains(text(), 'CNET')]]//a
```

it searches for the `div` with id = 'A' that has a `span` that contains the text 'CNET', from that `div` it selects the anchor-child-element