# Selenium: find the id of the parent of a certain item

Tags: python, html, selenium

Take this simple code:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="001">
    <div title="hi">hi</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I find the id "001" by knowing the title "hi" with this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@title='hi']")
```

I've already seen this: [Select parent element of known element in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577636/select-parent-element-of-known-element-in-selenium) but it doesn't work on Python

Comment: What do you mean by, "it doesn't work on Python"?

Comment: Did you try `child_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@title='hi']")` and then `parent_elem = child_element.find_elements_by_xpath('..')` Now to fetch the id simply do `parent_elem.get_attribute('id')`

Comment: @JayeshDoolani yes, but it says that *list* does not have *.find_elements_by_xpath* attribute. My code is: *elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@title='"+team+"']")*
 *padre = elem.find_elements_by_xpath('..')*

Comment: change the `find_elements_by_xpath` to `find_element_by_xpath`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First fetch the child `<div>` element which has the attribute `title='hi'`

`child_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='hi']")`

Then fetch that element's parent using the xpath `'..'`

`parent_elem = child_elem.find_element_by_xpath('..')`

Now, to fetch the parent element's attribute `id`, simply do

`parent_elem.get_attribute('id')`

Comment: The answer is right, however the real problem was that I put *find_elements_by_xpath* and not * find_element_by_xpath*, as you said above

Comment: You can just do it in one shot with the XPath, `//div[@title='hi']/..`.