# Protractor find parent element

Tags: selenium, protractor

```
<label class="radio inline check">

            <input class="input ng-new ng-valid" name="BookType" required="" type="radio">

            <!---->

            <!---->
            Fiction
</label>

<label class="radio inline check">   

            <input class="input ng-new ng-valid" name="BookType" required="" type="radio">

            <!---->

            <!---->
            NonFiction
</label>

<label class="radio inline check">

            <input class="input ng-new ng-valid" name="BookTypeReal" required="" type="radio">

            <!---->

            <!---->
            Fiction
</label>

<label class="radio inline check">   

            <input class="input ng-new ng-valid" name="BookTypeReal" required="" type="radio">

            <!---->

            <!---->
            Fantasy
</label>
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter

If I use

```
element.all(locator).filter(filterFn)
```

the text returned is empty.

How can I go to parent element `<label>` to get the text?

```
label[class="radio inline check"]
```

returns 60 elements where more than one getText will return same text so it won't be unique.

```
input[name="BookType"]
```

returns two elements where each element is unique.

Comment: What is the scenario you are trying to test? In my opinion, selenium tests should always know what they are looking for and not try to figure it out with some logic. So in this case, you would be looking for the element with text `Fiction` or `NonFiction` instead of figuring out what the text is if the value is static. It's hard to say for sure though since I'm not sure what your case is.

Comment: @mrfreester I am trying to click on radio button/label that has label Fiction

Comment: So you need the `input`? Or the `label`? You can try `//label[text()='Fiction']` or `//label[contains(text(),'Fiction')]` if there are weird spaces for the `label`. If you need the `input` you can put a `/input` at the end of that. If you can confirm that's what you're looking for and that works I can post as an answer.

Comment: @mrfreester //label[contains(text(),'Fiction')] or //label[text()='Fiction'] does not work. I have updated the code above to show there are many labels with same text 'Fiction', what makes each one unique is the input[name] value. I want to click on label which has text as Fiction and <input class="input ng-new ng-valid" name="BookType" required="" type="radio">

Comment: I think I understand now. So you're looking for this? `//label[contains(text(),'Fiction') and ./input[@name='BookType']]`. That's an xpath... unfortunately css selectors don't have a select parent :( which is too bad because css selectors are usually cleaner to read.

Comment: There is [this for css with children...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), but it's experimental so I probably would be careful to adopt it.

Comment: Could you provide the code what you have tried instead of just the html. I have an idea how to solve it but it would be better if there was more context. If you want to give it a try, you should use http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getDriver

Comment: @SUM, the easy way is directly with an XPath: `by.xpath("input[@name='BookTypeReal']/..")`. The other way is to use a JavaScript injection: `browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].parentElement", $("[name='BookTypeReal'"))`.

Comment: @cnishina Code I have tried (does not work for me):                                                             
 var inputRadio = element.all(by.css('input[name=\'BookType\']')).get(0).getWebElement();
       var labelText = inputRadio.getDriver().findElement(by.css('label[class*='radio inline']'));
        labelText.click();

Comment: Currently not at a computer to test this out but have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577636/select-parent-element-of-known-element-in-selenium the xpath with '..'  looks interesting

Comment: Could you share your `filter` function?

Answer (score 1):

I used the following approach using TypeScript:

```
import {by, ElementFinder} from 'protractor';

export interface ElementDescriptor {
  tag?: string;
  cssClass?: string;
}

async function matches(element: ElementFinder, parentDescription: ElementDescriptor): Promise<boolean> {
  const promises = [];
  if (parentDescription.tag) {
    promises.push(element.getTagName());
  }
  if (parentDescription.cssClass) {
    promises.push(element.getAttribute('class'));
  }

  let i = 0;
  const results: string[] = await Promise.all(promises);

  return (!parentDescription.tag || results[i++] === parentDescription.tag)
    && (!parentDescription.cssClass || results[i++].split(' ').includes(parentDescription.cssClass));
}

export async function findParent(element: ElementFinder, parentDescription: ElementDescriptor): Promise<ElementFinder> {
  let parent: ElementFinder;
  do {
    parent = element.element(by.xpath('..'));
  } while ((await parent.getTagName()) !== 'html' && !(await matches(parent, parentDescription)));
  return parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `<input>` tag whose `<label>` has text as **Fiction** and `<input>` tag has name as **BookType** you can use the following  `xpath` :

```
"//label[@class='radio inline check' and contains(normalize-space(), 'Fiction')]/input[@class='input ng-new ng-valid' and @name='BookType']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do it:

1. To get the parent element, as you mentioned. For this you can use `xpath`'s `ancestor` for it like this:

   `.//*[@name='BookType']/ancestor::label`
2. To get the text as the sibling of the element with `@name='BookType'`:

   `.//*[@name='BookType']/following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]`

Answer (score 0):

In Xpath if you want parent of input you can use `//input[name="BookType"]/..`

Answer (score 0):

i have framed this based on available details over the net. Please give a try.

```
element.all(by.css('.radio inline check')).filter(function(elem){
        return elem.element(by.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Fiction')]]")).getText() 
        }).then(function(filteredElements){
        filteredElements.first().element(by.css('input[name=BookType]')).click();
        });
```

Note: You may have some format issue in this.