# How to find the id of children in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm new to web development and I'm experimenting with Selenium in Python.

I want to find the id of the child below, given that I only know `class="entry-content"` as its parent.

Example html:

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div id="pl-154">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Example output:

`pl-154`

Thank you beforehand!

Update: Thank you all for the comments! However when I tried the code on the website I'm working with, it doesn't work and I'm not sure why.
[image: Code]

Comment: Answer for updated question can be find in below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45769799/10744050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for child you can use CSS SELECTOR or XPATH. I would recommend cssselector.

**CSS SELECTOR :**
If you have multiple div's with id inside `<div class="entry-content">`

```
div[class='entry-content']>div
```

The above css selector will give you all the divs which are inside `<div class="entry-content">`

you can try something like `div[class='entry-content']+div`

If you are looking for xpath it'd be like this :

```
//div[@class='entry-content']/div or //div[@class='entry-content']/child::div
```

Whatever you are using, make sure to use get_attribute(attribute name) to get the attribute value.

```
div_id_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='entry-content']/div").get_attribute('id')
print(div_id_value)
```

[CSS SELECTOR REFRENCE](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

[XPATH REFRENCE](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

Comment: @chocolatte : Share that html in text format along with error stack trace.

Comment: @chocolatte : Actually you can try with `div_id_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='entry-content']/div[@class='panel-layout']").get_attribute('id')
print(div_id_value)`

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why didn't `div_id_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='entry-content']/div").get_attribute('id')
` work in the first place? There's no error but the `div_id_value` was empty

Comment: @chocolatte : that could be because `//div[@class='entry-content']/div` might have multiple entries in DOM. Suggestion go to dev tool and check for the mentioned xpath and see how many entries are present.

Comment: I attached a picture of `<div class='entry-content'>` in my post, and there are 3 children divs inside it. So I just want to make sure, the original code only works if there's 1 child div, is that correct?

Comment: @chocolatte : Yes correct. Now you have 3 child's so you will have to distinguish which one to select, if not declared only first child should get preference

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `./child::*` expression with `xpath`

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='entry-content']")
child = element.find_element_by_xpath("./child::*")
idVal = child.get_attribute('id'))
```

Your `id` value should be stored in the `idVal` variable 
I'm not sure which version of Python you are using but this should work for Python3

Comment: Thank you! The first line works but in the second line, the child was empty. Does it only work if there's only one child?

Answer (score 1):

Below code will give you ID of the child object

```
id_Value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='entry-content']/div").get_attribute('id'))
```

Comment: What is String here ?

Comment: get_attribute returns a string and we are capturing it in a String "id_Value "  @cruisepandey

Comment: @RajanDomala : Why would you do that in Python ?

Comment: @cruisepandey typical Java guy answers, Sorry for that, updated the answer