# How to find an element which has a particular sub element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I want to get the text of the element with `td` tag. The text I want is "2021.08.13"

```
                         <tr>
                        <td><span>申请号：</span> <a 
 href="javascript:viewDetail(0);">CN202110930062.2</a> </td>
                        <td><span>申请日：</span> 2021.08.13 
                                                   </td>
                    </tr>
```

I tried the following XPath :

```
"td//span[.='申请日：']"
```

But I am getting the text value of `span` tag only.
Can anybody tell me the correct xpath or css selector for this?

Comment: This `2021.08.13` looks to be in td, how many td's are present in HTMLDOM ? Can you share bit more outerHTML ?

Comment: You are looking for the parent element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577636/select-parent-element-of-known-element-in-selenium

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the value is to get the whole cell value and then split with specific text to get the remaining value.

```
celltext=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[.//span[.='申请日：']]").text
lastpart=celltext.split('申请日：')[-1]
print(lastpart)
```

---

There is another way you could grab the value using javascript executor to get the lastchildnode.

```
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[.//span[.='申请日：']]")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If that string you need is the last text(), you could use:

1. the following-sibling axis like this :

   //td/span[.='申请日：']/following-sibling::text()
2. the last() text() like this

   //td[span[.='申请日：']]/text()[last()]

Comment: Does this answers your question?